# MySQL - reference column in function call

Tags: mysql, function, reference

I got a number in a table, which I want to use for the DATE_ADD function in MySQL.

So something like this:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2011-01-02', '+INTERVAL some_table.column DAY') AS newdate FROM some_table
```

This will however not work, as MySQL will not understand some_table.column is a column with a value etc. Any help please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use quotes:

```
SELECT DATE_ADD('2011-01-02', INTERVAL some_table.column) AS newdate FROM some_table
```

Comment: I'm trying to do this more specifically: SELECT DATE_ADD('2011-01-02', +INTERVAL column DAY) AS newdate FROM table. It gives me SQL error.

Comment: There shouldn't be a '+' in that statement.